# Parse special characters with matching regular characters

Tags: sqlite

I have a search input where you can search for wines. I have some wines that contain characters like `é` (e.g. `Dom Pérignon`).

Currently if I am to type `Dom Perignon` then I wont get the above example wine. But what I wish to achieve is that if I typed `e` instead of `é` I would still get the `Dom Pérignon` wine.

The search mechanism itself is basic.

The input:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for wine or producer..." ng-change="search()" ng-model="data.search">
```

And the SQL querying:

```
DB.query("SELECT id, name, ... FROM wines WHERE name LIKE ? OR house_name LIKE ? LIMIT 20", [searchFilter + '%', searchFilter + '%'])
```

How could I achieve the ability that typing `e` would also parse wines containing `é`?

Answer (score 1):

I would add another column to your database containing a 'normalised' version of each name, then normalise each search term that the user enters and check for a match using that.

Normalisation could involve substituting accented characters for unaccented equivalents, converting upper case characters to lower case, and removing spaces and hyphens etc, that way you could catch many other common mis-spellings.